# Getting errors when running a grunt.js task

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, npm

I'm using the uncss task with grunt.js in order reduce the size of my CSS by removing unused rules.

Here's the url for uncss: https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss

This is my Gruntfile.js setup:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({

    uncss: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                'docs/tidy.css': ['docs/index.html']
            }
        },
        options: {
            compress:true
        }
    },

    processhtml: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                'docs/tidy.css': ['docs/index.html']
            }
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-uncss');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-processhtml');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['uncss','processhtml']);

};
```

And this is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ProjectName",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.2",
    "grunt-uncss": "~0.1.5",
    "grunt-processhtml": "~0.2.7"
  }
}
```

All the dependencies were installed fine, without any errors...

But when I run `grunt` or `grunt uncss`, I get the following error:

```
Running "uncss:dist: (uncss) task
[SyntaxError: Unmatched selector:(http]
>> Uncssing source "docs/index.html" failed.
Warning: Uncss failed. Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.
```

**Does anybody have any idea what this error means and how to correct it?** I searched and searched and I was unable to find any documentation that covers this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're using an unsupported selector, like in this issue : https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss/issues/14

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could have a syntax error in your css. Either that or you have a bug in your css. You could run using `--force` like the error hints at, which I'm assuming will ignore that single rule.

You could look for a selector that looks like this in your css file: `(http`

Comment: The css works just fine on my project, and running `--force` just returns the same error. There's no such thing as a selector `(http]`... The beginning bracket is part of the error output - so is the end bracket.

Comment: good point @akaryatrh - that seems like it could be it. you should add it as an answer